# how to build appbundle in release mode with real device in flutter?

Tags: flutter, release, app-bundle

I have built an app in flutter using android studio and am trying to release it on the play store.

According to https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration, "Run flutter build appbundle (Running flutter build defaults to a release build.)"
[image]

However, when I try to upload this on the play console, I get the error message that "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode."
aslo I swiched to release mode too but it is same.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your file => New => import project => open same projects android file in new tab => then go to build =>generate signed bundle/apk